# How to import submodules in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I am trying to import the subdirectory of a module in Pycharm. This never seems to work for me. I get a red underline under the subdirectory name, does anyone know why this might be?

In this case the autoextract package has been installed, but it seems `sync` has not been installed. How can I install `sync` and get rid of the red underline?

I have this issue regularly with many different packages, so it's not specific to this package.

[image]

Comment: Did you install [scrapinghub-autoextract](https://pypi.org/project/scrapinghub-autoextract/)?

Comment: Yes that worked without any trouble